# VHDL processes - static like function in C

Tags: vhdl

I've written C for 20+ years, and now I'm learning VHDL so I have some dumb n00b questions, I can't seem to find when I search.

In C code, you can have one one file, with one giant function that is 1000 lines long - It is sort of dumb to do that, it makes it really hard to follow. The better practice is to split your larger function up into some smaller static functions, this makes your C code far more readable.

I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing with VHDL procedures, aka: little static functions, I don't find examples of this.  In C, you tell the compiler (actually the optimizer) to inline and flatten your code into a highly optimized thing.

I don't really want lots of "VHDL" files, one per function or sub block.

Using a UART as an example, I've seen lots of giant switch/case statements in VHDL - what I am looking for some examples with lots of little processes instead.

this is what I don't want: https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/module-uart-serial-port-rs232.html

The TX code is 100 some odd lines long, one giant function/process. It's also indented multiple times.

In C, you combat that type of stuff by using small static functions, in quasi-C-vhdl, you would do this:

```
   p_UART : process( ... )
   begin
      case v_STATE is
         when s_IDLE => handle_idle();
         when s_START => handle_start();
         when s_SHIFTING => shift_next();
         when s_DONE => shift_done();
      end case;
   end process;
```

What I don't seem to find is examples like the above, where each state is a nested process of some type

The advantage of the above method in C is this:

- each state is encapsulated in a small thing, easily understood, you are not scrolling through 200 or so lines of VHDL, making it hard to read and follow.
- each time you create a sub process you reset the indentation level to 0, when you have 100 to 200 lines of code, you tend to shift off the right hand side of the screen... again making the code hard to read and follow.
- The compiler's optimizer can INLINE your little functions better then you can ever do this, it makes fewer mistakes and can optimize your dumb code better then you can. That's it's job and it often does it better then you can.

I'm trying to figure out the same syntax or design pattern VHDL.

Or maybe I am using the wrong search terms? Not sure.

Comment: Do you have a specific VHDL [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? VHDL is intended to describe hardware behavior in a virtual machine (a simulator).  A subset can be used by a synthesis tool to map an elaborated design network to a netlist of target silicon primitives. [Anything with sequential logic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkd03urs3rj7q07/uart_tx_tb.vhdl?dl=1) (e.g. clock edge conditional assignments without complete coverage) describes a finite state machine.

Comment: Signals, and variables declared in process statements, declarations of objects of protected or access types are elaborated (take effect) once. Subprograms declarations are dynamically elaborated when called. Process statements are sequences of statements whose execution suspends and subsequently resumes in wait statements. A process with a sensitivity list has an implicit wait on the sensitivity list as it's last statement. The first statement in a process is executed after the last. Signal updates are scheduled for future simulation cycles.

Comment: Maybe you want to look into VHDL functions and procedures? The only thing they will bring is encapsulating small bits of code. But the generated logic will be the same. But you may upset other developers as lots of small functions/procedures would not be "standard" and may frustrate their reading. The code you posted is pretty standard

Comment: Just do it. In your sample fragment, your procedures shouldn't have empty parameter lists; Unlike C, you only add parameter lists if there are parameters. But there's nothing stopping you using functions and procedures. If you're ranting that there are a lot of badly written VHDL examples out there ... well, you're not wrong. Just be the change...